# get dictionary key in property getter

Tags: c#

Is there any way I can check if value is null

```
Dictionary <string,object> coll = new Dictionary <string,object> ();

public Dictionary <string,object> Pdict
{
    get
    {
        //can I check here which key is requested
        //if(coll[keyname ] == null)coll[keyname ] =           new myclass();
        return coll;
    }
    set
    {
        coll = value;
    }
}

// when I do this I need key name in property getter.
object obj = Pdict[key];
```

Purpose is I want to initialize the object which is requested and not all.

Comment: `can I check here which key is requested`, you are not requesting a key, you are asking for the entire dictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot check the requested key in this setup, because the getter is returning the entire dictionary object, not necessarily indexing it. For example, one could access methods on your dictionary

```
if(myObj.Pdict.ContainsKey(someKey))
```

Instead, if you want to limit access, you could implement an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on your class and hide you dictionary.

```
protected Dictionary<string, object> coll = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        if(coll.ContainsKey(key) == false)
            coll.Add(key, this.CreateObjectForDictionary(key))
        return coll[key];
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you want to make sure your dictionary is a dictionary, you could implement a new class, inherit from dictionary, and create objects every time an access is requested against an object which does not yet exist.

Comment: This is what I exactly need. I implemented a new class but now I am getting error "Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 .......get_Child()"

Comment: Can you provide complete code. Your code giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

> can I check here which key is requested

No, you can't. You right now have a property that will return the entire dictionary object, which you then use to select a key/value from.

An option is to make a function instead that will return only the value you are looking for, or do something if the value is null/missing.

```
Dictionary <string,object> coll = new Dictionary <string,object> ();

public object GetCollValue(string key)
{
    if (!coll.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        //logic for "not exists"
    }

    var value = coll[key];

    if (value == null)
    {
        //logic for "is null"
    }

    return value;
}
```

Now just call the method with they key you want.

```
object obj = GetCollValue(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this helper function to get a value from your dictionary without running into exceptions for missing keys:

```
    public object GetValue(string key, object defaultValue = null)
    {
        Object val;
        if (Pdict.TryGetValue(key, out val)) return val;

        return defaultValue;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a normal property use an indexer:

```
public object this[ string key ]
{
    get
    {
        return coll[ key ];
    }
    set
    {
        coll[ key ] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That only works if the class _is_ a Dictionary...not if it _has_ a Dictionary.

Comment: Your example attempts to index `this`.  What is `this`?  A dictionary.  Meaning that the class itself must be a dictionary.  Not what OP has or wants.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it as a property.  You could use a method instead:

```
public Object GetDictValue(String Key)
{
    if (Pdict.ContainsKey(Key))
        return Pdict[Key];
    Pdict.Add(Key, null);
    return null;
}
```

And then only use the property to retrieve the entire Dictionary.

Comment: You can do it as an indexer